# days after start of security pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I am using this to get the number of days associated with current price:

```
start = time == timestamp(2010,6,29,0,0) // First TSLA Date

days = security("NASDAQ:TSLA", "D", barssince(start))
```

This seems to work if I say do it on

```
days = security("KRAKEN:ETHUSD", "D", barssince(start))
```

but for TSLA it does not work. Any ideas why? The days are not returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll go on lower than 1D timeframe you will see that the tradingview's data show the first bar at timestamp(2010,6,29,9,30) (exchange time)

```
//@version=4
study("Start", overlay = true)
start = time == timestamp(2010,6,29,9,30)
days = security("NASDAQ:TSLA", "D", barssince(start))
bgcolor(start? color.red : na) // highlight the start
```